# Best way to add/retrieve data to/from rabbitMQ queues

Tags: java, rabbitmq

Consider this scenario:

> Continuously creating and filling different queues in `RabbitMQ` and each queue
>   must be consumed with at most **ONE** thread at a time

please note this is still in design stage but will be coded in Java(not that it should make any difference):

I could think of two ways of doing this:

Writer:

```
 for each incoming info do:
       create a new channel with a given queuname then write  data  MQ using this channel
```

Reader:

```
for each Thread t do:
  create a new Channel for a next queue name and pass the Channel to t
```

_______________________or_______________________

```
create one channel
```

Writer:

```
for each incomming data do:
  get the queue name for data and write to mq using already difined channel
```

Reader:

```
for each Thread t do:
  assign next queue name to t , so it uses one single channel to retrieve data.
```

1. So what are **pros** and **cons** of each implementation?
2. Is there something that I might be missing here?